# Could the process of zabbix-server setup be automated?

Tags: installation, zabbix

When a zabbix-service is installed, the admin need to setup it by access http://{zabbix-server-host}/zabbix/ with browser, and click the "Next" on each page of a setup wizard. Although the only input field is the password of "root" user, it seems that some data in database is updated (but I am not sure what it exactly is).

Could the setup process be automated? For example, can I write a script by accessing database or any configuration files to finish the setup process?

Answer (score 5):

Just create /etc/zabbix/zabbix.conf.php with following contents:

```
<?php
// Zabbix GUI configuration file
global $DB;

$DB['TYPE']     = 'MYSQL';
$DB['SERVER']   = 'localhost';
$DB['PORT']     = '0';
$DB['DATABASE'] = 'zabbix';
$DB['USER']     = 'zabbix';
$DB['PASSWORD'] = 'zabbix';

// SCHEMA is relevant only for IBM_DB2 database
$DB['SCHEMA'] = '';

$ZBX_SERVER      = 'localhost';
$ZBX_SERVER_PORT = '10051';
$ZBX_SERVER_NAME = 'zabbix';

$IMAGE_FORMAT_DEFAULT = IMAGE_FORMAT_PNG;
?>
```

Comment: Indeed it work for me. And I use that just as template for ansible auto deployment to bypass web installation.

Comment: don't forget to install php mysql support: `apt-get install -y php-mysql`

Answer (score 1):

You need to create database, create schema, load initial data and write a config file with correct username and password to access the database.
The schema and initial data are part of the server distribution.

Comment: I did all of these. But I still need to go through the setup wizard. What exactly does the setup.php do?

Answer (score 0):

You could have a look at the setup .php files. It should be possible to implement these datebase queries on your own to make them work with an automated script. On the other hand you could simple use an command line based tool to handle http requests (Cookies, POST, GET) and just send your dynamic data to the zabbix setup using this tool (so implementing a very simple browser). Of course this command line tool can then be called by another script. My last recommend is to favor because its less error prone I think.

Answer (score 0):

You can directly modify zabbix configuration file but it may not verify the required settings and details like PHP settings.

Also, direct modification may create an error. Hence, it is recommended to use the GUI to complete the verification and configuration of zabbix server. It is the most preferable way to complete the configuration.

This process should take few minutes and it is not a time consuming process.

Regards,